# Can we capture the definition to be a Mersenne prime in an identity only involving the arithmetic function $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\text{nmod k}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, conjectures, arithmetic-functions

Let  $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\text{nmod k}$ the **sum of remainder function**, denoting $\sigma(n)$ as **the sum of divisors function**, it is know that for each $n>1$ 
$$S(n)-S(n-1)=2n-1-\sigma(n),$$
is as curiority an statement due to **Lucas**. Too  it is know the identities that we can show for **perfect nubmers, almos perferct numbers and prime numbers.** See [here](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/RemaindersFinal.pdf). On the other hand it is know some attempts and theorems that look capture the definition of a sequence only in terms of an arithmetic function.

My attempt was use previous function to show that

> **Fact 1.** If $m=2^p-1$ is a **Mersenne prime** then
>   $$m\left(S\left(m\right)-S\left(m-1\right)\right)+S\left(\frac{m-1}{2}\right)-S\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)=m(m-2).$$

$$$$

The proof is show that then $m(m-2)-\left(m-(2^p-1)\right)=m(m-2)$. Notice that the second summand $-\left(m-(2^p-1)\right)$ is zero.

> **Fact 2.** Conversely if $m>3$ is an odd integer and safisties the equation in previous fact, then this satisfies 
>   $$m^2+\sigma\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)=m\sigma(m),$$
>   and thus denoting $m=2k-1$ one has 
>   $$4k^2+1-4k+\sigma(k)=(2k-1)\sigma(2k-1).$$

$$$$

> **Computational facts.** I don't know if previous identity involving the sum of divisor function for odd integers is in the literature. My computations were that only obtain Mersenne primes when I use a computer. On the other hand as I've said there are relationships between the formulas for primes and almost perfect numbers, for this reason I am confusing. Also I know equation, a relation problem, here in spanish, [PROBLEMA 55, page 156-157](http://gaceta.rsme.es/abrir.php?id=609), where * means unsolved, for which I don't know how clarify this

$$$$

> **Question.** **Can you get a closed formula involving only the sum of remainders function, that isn't superfluous, and does capture the definition of Mersenne primes?** Is this 
>   $$m\left(S\left(m\right)-S\left(m-1\right)\right)+S\left(\frac{m-1}{2}\right)-S\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)=m(m-2)?$$
>   If you **can show an odd integer $m$, as counterexample** for this last equation I will apprecite, since I don't made computations for this equation. Can you clarify my doubts about if my computations were empty by comparision with the cited literature? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I hope that there aren't mistakes. Feel free to update my post.

Comment: you give the formulas without motivating : where do they come from, why and how they could be true, what you hope to get

Comment: The way of deduction of previous formulas were not serious, I did understand that were without mathematical contents. Sometimes my maths are tricks like as symbolic computations with the hope that something works, instead of a logical reasoning. ON the other hand I would like to write Mersenne primes as a function of remainders when is divided by $1, 2, \ldots n$. Thanks @user1952009